# Bash Error "syntax error: operand expected" but operand existing

Tags: bash

There is a substraction operation that results in an error, however it seems there are two operands given:

```
PREV="$(intranet -r)"
PREV=${PREV/Revision: /}      ## results in "11072"
REV="$(intranet -r)"
REV=${REV/Revision: /}     ## results in "11072"
RDIFF=$(( ${REV} - ${PREV} ))        ## throws error
```

> /usr/local/bin/updateAll: line 36: 11072
>    - 11072  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "11072
>    - 11072  ")

I tried putting REV/PREV in "*brackets*" and without "*$*" with no success.

**EDIT:**
The actual result of

> intranet -r | sed -n l

is

> \033[96mRevision: 11072$
>
> \033[0m$

(Because the output is color-formatted)

Comment: What is the actual output of `intranet -r`?

Comment: It outputs: "Revision: 11072" (without brackets)

Comment: More like `intranet -r | sed -n l` (same with `-u`).

Comment: I assume there could be a " " (space) after the digit in final $REV. Would that be a problem? Do you have an idea of how to trim that digit-string?

Comment: I see the same error with `bash -c $'echo $(( \u200b11072 - 11072 ))'` or `bash -c $'echo $(( \a11072 - 11072 ))'`. I'd bet the output has some invisible characters.

Comment: You are absoluteley right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the color formatting. I added a second case "intranet -R" (uppercase "R") without color formatting - works like a charm.